# Unable to perform the priority-based execution in azurecosmosdb

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-python-sdk

I've tried to run the query on the container (azurecosmosdb) using the parameter 'priority_level="High"' it was throwing below exception while trying to run the below code.

Note:- below code written in python

[image]

Error details:-

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images for code-snippets and/or log outputs. Please include the actual text using code formatting as established in Community Guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most probably running an old version of `azure-sdk-for-python`. The `priority_level` argument preview feature was only merged into the `Azure:main` branch on October 11th.

You can check out the PR [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/32441)

Also, as-per the [release notes on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/releases/tag/azure-cosmos_4.5.2b2), you're going to need to enable the `priority_level` preview feature on the `account level` in Azure.

**EDIT**
You can find details regarding Priority Based Execution for CosmosDB on [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-priority-based-execution-in-azure-cosmos-db-preview/) post from Microsoft.

According to this, you'll need to fill out a nomination for to enable to feature for your account [here.](https://forms.microsoft.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR_kUn4g8ufhFjXbbwUF1gXFUMUQzUzFZSVkzODRSRkxXM0RKVDNUSDBGNi4u)

Comment: Thanks for your time akseli, would like to know how to use the latest version of azure-sdk-for-python. would you please help me with the steps that i need to approach..

Comment: I've installed the latest version (azure-cosmos 4.5.2b2) and saw some changes in _base.py . I will give it a try and will update if it worked or not.. Thanks, akselli..

Comment: Issue got resolved with the latest version (azure-cosmos 4.5.2b2) successfully runs   the query on the container (azurecosmosdb) using the parameter 'priority_level="High"'